# Django EmailMessage Attachments attribute

Tags: django

I try to send in one email more than one attachments all are in PDF this is my code

```
for pdf_files in glob.glob(path+str(customer)+'*.*'):

                    get_filename = os.path.basename(pdf_files)


                    list_files = [get_filename]




                    attachment = open(path+get_filename, 'rb')

                    email = EmailMessage('Report for'+' '+customer,
                        'Report Date'+' '+cust+', '+cust, to=['asd@asd.com'])

                    email.attachments(filename=list_files, content=attachment.read(), mimetype='application/pdf')

                    email.send()
```

Here is what the Django documentation says about the attachments attribute.

> attachments: A list of attachments to put on the message. These can be either `email.MIMEBase.MIMEBase` instances, or `(filename, content, mimetype)` triples.

When I try to run this code using the Attachments I always get this error

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but I passing a list of files like the the doc says please can some one have an example. I look out everywhere and all people use attach and attach_files but both functions only send one attachment only in an email.

Answer (score 1):

You should construct a list of attachments, and use it when you create the `EmailMessage`. If you want to send all the attachments with a single email, then you need to create a list of all the attachments first, then send the email *outside* of the loop.

I've simplified the code slightly so you'll have to adjust it, but hopefully this will get you started.

```
# Loop through the list of filenames and create a list
# of attachments, using the (filename, content, mimetype) 
# syntax.

attachments = []  # start with an empty list
for filename in filenames:
    # create the attachment triple for this filename
    content = open(filename, 'rb').read()
    attachment = (filename, content, 'application/pdf')
    # add the attachment to the list
    attachments.append(attachment)

# Send the email with all attachments
email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'Body goes here', 'from@example.com',
        ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'], attachments=attachments)
email.send()
```

The `email.attachments` attribute is the actual list of attachments for the `email` instance. It is a Python list, so trying to call it like a method raises an error.

Comment: I really appreciate your help it was good the thing is that still getting the same result 3 emails each emails with one attachment also I have to put outside the content variable and the mimetype variable and declare those outside and put it inside the attachments list otherwise there is a syntax error.

Comment: I've fixed the syntax error. To send all attachments with a single email, you need to create a list containing all of the attachments, and then send the email *outside* of the loop.

Comment: Awesome!! I think the main error was to send the email inside the loop thanks very much you save the day.